# How to INSERT INTO ... SELECT from 2 tables to 1 table with Foreign Key constraints

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a brand new table that I am trying to copy data into from 2 different tables. All data is required, and thus needs to be in the same insert statement. One of the pieces of data is simply a foreign key from a lookup table. The 2 origination tables have nothing to do with each other as one of them is a brand new table linking to this new table.

I am having issues getting the insert into … select statement to work, and could use some help. The following query I came up with is syntactically correct, but I am getting an error.

```
insert into destination_table (fk_name_id, name, description, cycle_time, hand_offs, touch_time, fk_origin_id)
values ((select id from lookup_table where name = 'some name'), 
        (select ot.name, ot.description, ot.ctroi, ot.horoi, ot.ttroi, tc.id
         from origin_table ot
         left join table_a ta on ot.taid = ta.id
         left join table b tb on ta.tbid = tb.id
         left join table_c tc on tb.tcid = tc.id));
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

I've been looking at this for a few days now and have scoured Stack Overflow and the varying search engines but have not seen this particular issue addressed.

The only workaround I can think of is to do the lookup table search separate, I couldn't get a WITH clause to work on the insert, then hardcode it into the insert. However, I would really like to not do that as this will eventually be run in different environments, and a dynamic way is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `INSERT INTO...VALUES` use `INSERT INTO...SELECT`:

```
insert into destination_table (fk_name_id, name, description, cycle_time, hand_offs, touch_time, fk_origin_id)
select 
  (select id from lookup_table where name = 'some name'), 
  ot.name, ot.description, ot.ctroi, ot.horoi, ot.ttroi, tc.id
  from origin_table ot
  left join table_a ta on ot.taid = ta.id
  left join table b tb on ta.tbid = tb.id
  left join table_c tc on tb.tcid = tc.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a cross join

```
insert into destination_table (
  fk_name_id
  , name
  , description
  , cycle_time
  , hand_offs
  , touch_time
  , fk_origin_id)
values ( 
    select t2.id, t1.* from 
    (select ot.name, ot.description, ot.ctroi, ot.horoi, ot.ttroi, tc.id
     from origin_table ot
     left join table_a ta on ot.taid = ta.id
     left join table b tb on ta.tbid = tb.id
     left join table_c tc on tb.tcid = tc.id) t1
     cross  join  ( select id 
      from lookup_table 
      where name = 'some name') t2 
  );
```